# problema #1005 - No puedo crear tabla, Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: mysql

Este es el problema que tengo no me deja crear la tabla

```
CREATE TABLE `egallego_Gestion`.`USR_GRP_USR_M` ( `ID` INT(3) NOT NULL , `USR` INT(2) NOT NULL 
, `USR_GRP` INT(2) NOT NULL , `ALT_USR` INT(2) NOT NULL , `ALT_TIM` DATE NOT NULL 
, `MOD_USR` INT(2) NOT NULL , `MOD_TIM` DATE NOT NULL , `OFF` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL 
, `OFF_USR` INT(2) NOT NULL , `OFF_TIM` DATE NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Esta no es la tabla que provoca el fallo, por favor edita y coloca además la tabla donde estas intentado hacer l llave foránea

Comment: pero yo no estoy intentando hacer ninguna llave foranea, donde puedo mirar?

Comment: donde hay llaves foraneas

Comment: De acuerdo con el mensaje de error si que lo tratas de hacer pues `foreign key` es llave foránea

Comment: y donde puedo ver donde estan esas llaves foraneas?

Comment: Edita y agrega la declaración de todas tus tablas que intentas hacer

Comment: solo me manda el error cuando creo especificamente esa tabla pero no encuentro el error de la clave foranea

Comment: anteriormente esa tabla estaba creada y de repente se desaparecio sola

Comment: Ese error suele ocurrir cuando en un `CREATE TABLE` o en un `ALTER TABLE` intentas crear una llave foránea (`Foreign key`) basándote en una tabla que no existe. Debes revisar bien todo, incluyendo los posibles `TRIGGER` que tengas, si dejaste tu ordenador encendido y anduvo el gato o el perro por allí o lo que sea, pues dices que hay tablas que desparecen. Revisa también si no tienes un troyano... en fin, las tablas no desparecen solas, alguien las estará haciendo desaparecer.

Comment: Me acaba de pasar lo mismo que a @MateoGallegoGonzales. Se borró una tabla sola al intentar hacer un update de una clave foranea. Y ahora es una tabla fantasma. Pruebo con un DROP TABLE xxx; y el motor no la encuentra. Pero si intento recrearla, me da el error 1005.